# Marshal Badge requirements causing large backlog

Tags: feature-request, badges, flag-badges

I have noticed from the few times I have flagged in the last year that almost all of them timed out, unreviewed. I was then scheming today, as I often do, on how to get a gold medal easily. Theoretically all you would have to do is just flag any and every question submitted based on a brief reading of its contents, selecting the option that best fits, whether it is actually worthy of flagging or not.

One possible fix for this would be to make the Marshal badge similar to the Unsung Hero badge; while it currently requires 500 helpful flags, maybe those 500 should have to be 25% or more of the total flags. This would prevent people from flagging questions frivolously, relieving the backlog, and making the site more accurate, so that good flags don't slip through the cracks.

Just a suggestion. Please respond with your own ideas on how to fix this, or why its fine how it is. Its just a thought.

Comment: People with less than 25% helpful flags will be rate limited or flag-banned I believe.

Comment: True, although as of last year the flag ban policy isn't much of a ban: "Depending on when and how those declined flags were cast, this block could last for as little as a day, and won't ever be longer than a week."

Comment: @oMiKeY: "*I was then scheming today, as I often do, on how to get a gold medal easily.*" Um, why? Stop treating badges like they're candy. Do your job, make the site better, and you'll get the badges you *deserve*.

Comment: Who’s angry? Everyone who’s responded to you seems pretty chilled. In case you are: don’t confuse downvotes with anger, they, of course, carry no emotion

Comment: It is an initiative, a suggestion. What suggestion wouldn't be "opinion-based"? They may be accepted or rejected (most of them is rejected), and it is based on the *opinion* of the community. If this question would be closed, all the questions should be closed about a suggestion - including the few *accepted* ones. Thus, I suggest "Leave Open".

Comment: Btw, I have multiple marshal badges (on multiple sites) and my experience is that it happens nearly automatically if you pass through all the 6 (8) queues. I doesn't require additional work. Get your 8 steward badges and also you will see.

Answer (score 10):

> Theoretically all you would have to do is just flag any and every question submitted based on a brief reading of its contents, selecting the option that best fits, whether it is actually worthy of flagging or not.

NOPE.

This would get you flag banned by the system *way before* you get close to Marshal Badge.If not, a Moderator can be notified of such a behavior and it could be handled.
Also, there is a daily flag limit which may expand depending on your accepted flag count and rate(Will update if I get the accurate measure).

While the number of flags getting aged away could be a problem that needs addressing, the cause is not people flagging recklessly pursuing badges.

Answer (score 9):

You have 4 flags raised in the last year. To get the Marshal badge, you need to raise helpful flags. It's true that some age away. You'll also find that some get disputed and declined outright. But, you still have to raise flags to get any of those out comes. To get the Marshal badge, you have to raise 500 helpful flags.

Start using your flagging privileges is the first step in getting the badge.